# pdf2json: how to customize the output json file?

Tags: json, parsing, pdf

Can I customize the output of pdf2json command line utility so that the output json file has a specific structure?

I'm trying to extract data from a pdf (see figure below) and store it as a json file.

[image: fig 1]

I tried `pdf2json -f [input directory or pdf file]`. The command does output a json file that contains the information I need, but it also contains a lot of information I don't need:

> `{"formImage":{"Transcoder":"pdf2json@0.6.6","Agency":"","Id":{"AgencyId":"","Name":"","MC":false,"Max":1,"Parent":""},"Pages":[{"Height":49.5,"HLines":[{"x":13.111828125000002,"y":4.678418750000001,"w":0.44775000000000004,"l":78.96384375000001},{"x":13.111828125000002,"y":44.074375,"w":0.44775000000000004,"l":78.96384375000001}],"VLines":[],"Fills":[{"x":0,"y":0,"w":0,"h":0,"clr":1}],"Texts":[{"x":13.632429687500002,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":4.163000000000001,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"abundant","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":25.021517303398443,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":4.139000000000001,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"positive%3A1","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":32.38324218816407,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":4.412000000000001,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"negative%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":40.12887364285157,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":3.1670000000000003,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"anger%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":46.1237223885547,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":5.993,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"anticipation%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":56.09123069480469,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":3.8400000000000003,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"disgust%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":63.0324864791797,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":2.4170000000000003,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"fear%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":67.97264684597657,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":2.109,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"joy%3A1","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":72.47968185183595,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":4.013,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"sadness%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":79.66421908894532,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":4.178000000000001,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"surprise%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":87.08078776941407,"y":4.382312499999998,"w":2.8930000000000002,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":[{"T":"trust%3A0","S":-1,"TS":[0,13.9091,0,0]}]},{"x":13.632429687500002,"y":5.017468750000002,"w":2.4480000000000004,"clr":0,"A":"left","R":`

I only need the text from the pdf file. I don't need any information about the format. So I need something like this:

```
{"data":
    {
    "abundant": {
        "positive":1,
        "negative":0,
        "anger":0,
        ...
        },
    "abuse": {...},
    "abutment": {...},
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found any work arounds to make it possible?

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva no I parsed the output of pdf2json to get the data I wanted

Answer (score -1):

I've build a Node.js module that uses pdf2json and some simple math to extract the table data from the PDF. The output is an array of rows.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2table